# Undesired output for php array creation

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to create an array from input in a textarea.

I have a file named with a textarea.The textarea might contain values like(exactly the way it looks):

```
CREATE this.

DO that.

STOP it.
```

Basically,I want to use **PHP** to  :

Create an array out of the values given by the textarea for example,the array madefrom th values of  the textarea above is meant to be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => create this
    [1] => do this
    [2] => Stop it
```

)

I'v e tried the following code:

```
 <?php 

    $wholecode=$_POST['code'];

     $code=explode('.',trim(strtolower($wholecode)));//convert code to array


    $words=explode(' ', $code);


print_r($code);
```

I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => create this
    [1] => 

do this
    [2] => 

stop it
    [3] => 
)
```

As it clearly shows,that is not what I want.Please help

Comment: `$code=explode('.'.PHP_EOL,trim(strtolower($wholecode)));` try with this part ?

Comment: You are currently splitting this at the dots only, which of course leaves the line break characters in place.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm `'.PHP_EOL'` is the literal _text_ `.PHP_EOL` ... constants do not get replaced in single or double quoted strings, you need to use string concatenation in this place: `'.'.PHP_EOL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct approach using a simple regex pattern to explode on dots followed by zero or more whitespace characters.  No mopping up after splitting.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vImI9))

```
$_POST['code'] = 'CREATE this.

DO that.

STOP it.';

var_export(preg_split('~\.\s*~', strtolower($_POST['code']), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'create this',
  1 => 'do that',
  2 => 'stop it',
)
```

As a variable...

```
$array = preg_split('~\.\s*~', strtolower($_POST['code']), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Explanation transferred from my comment:

Pattern Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jygaQ1/1

There are 3 dots in your sample data.  The first two have whitespaces characters that immediately follow.  The final dot has no trailing whitespace characters.

The `\s*` means "match zero or more whitespace characters.

`-1` means perform unlimited explosions.

`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` means that on the final explosion (the last dot) there will be an empty element generated, but `preg_split()` will disregard it in the output array.

Comment: Please can you explain it to me..ur answer

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jygaQ1/2  This is what we call a "rabbithole"  You can keep extending the requirements, but then I'll keep refining the pattern, but I'll end up wasting a lot of my time doing lots of edits.  It is best that you fully represent your problem and the multitude of ways that your input text can vary when you first post your question.

Comment: Also,if there is no string at all..it prints `Array()`

Comment: ...rabbit hole.  What were you hoping for if not an empty array?  Our comments are too many, we must tidy up this page.

Comment: Done that.I'm trying to build something like a programming language with it.That is why I was asking all thesese questions.Please dont be mad

Comment: I actually dont know whether you're just kidding

Comment: I have another question...are you still there?

Comment: I'm not always here, but I always come back. (I've been volunteering here for 673 consecutive days)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to tidy up the array contents after creating it.  You have things like new lines and potentially other whitespace around the content.

This uses [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to `trim()` each entry in the array.  Then uses [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any empty elements (calling it with no callback will do this).

```
$wholecode=$_POST['code'];

$code=explode('.',trim(strtolower($wholecode)));//convert code to array
$code=array_map("trim", $code );
$code = array_filter($code);
print_r($code);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make all that to a single line?

Comment: @bestboy `$array = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode('.',trim(strtolower($_POST['code'])))));`